# Visualforce page for each Record Type

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have 2 record types in opportunity object, LSS and LDD if user selects LDD i need to navigate to custom visualforce page. How accomplish this.

Thanks,
Anil Kumar

Comment: What is firing the action of navigation to the custom visualforce page?

Comment: In the  custom visualforce page i need to display all the opportunity fields with validations